# C++ Unable to read from file and write to file in the same run

Tags: c++, file-io, readfile, writefile

I'm attempting to read an inventory in from 3 files in one function and then rewrite those 3 files in another. When I try each of these functions individually, they both seem to work. But when I use both of them in the same run, the text files either are empty or having missing info. Is there any way that code should be changed when reading and writing to the same file?

```
void Inventory::fromFile(std::string filename){
std::ifstream infile(filename);
if (infile){
    if(filename == "game.txt"){
        while (infile){
            if(infile){
                std::string strInput;
                std::getline(infile, strInput);
                if(strInput.length()>0){
                    std::stringstream splitter(strInput);
                    std::string title,price,copies,condition,genre,rating,maker;
                    getline(splitter,title,',');
                    getline(splitter,price,',');
                    getline(splitter,copies,',');
                    getline(splitter,condition,',');
                    getline(splitter,genre,',');
                    getline(splitter,rating,',');
                    getline(splitter,maker,',');
                    Game* g = new Game(stoi(copies), stof(price), title, genre,rating, to_bool(condition),maker);
                    gameStock.add(g);
                    std::cout << "\nRead:\t" << g->toString() << "\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(filename == "console.txt"){
        while (infile){
            if(infile){
                std::string strInput;
                std::getline(infile, strInput);
                if(strInput.length()>0){
                    std::stringstream splitter(strInput);
                    std::string title,price,copies,condition,edition,maker,warranty;
                    getline(splitter,title,',');
                    getline(splitter,price,',');
                    getline(splitter,copies,',');
                    getline(splitter,condition,',');
                    getline(splitter,edition,',');
                    getline(splitter,maker,',');
                    getline(splitter,warranty,',');
                    Console* c = new Console(stoi(copies), stof(price), title, edition,maker, stoi(warranty), to_bool(condition));
                    gameStock.add(c);
                    std::cout << "\nRead:\t" << c->toString() << "\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(filename == "accessory.txt"){
        while (infile){
            if(infile){
                std::string strInput;
                std::getline(infile, strInput);
                if(strInput.length()>0){
                    std::stringstream splitter(strInput);
                    std::string title,price,copies,condition,consoleTo,warranty;
                    getline(splitter,title,',');
                    getline(splitter,price,',');
                    getline(splitter,copies,',');
                    getline(splitter,condition,',');
                    getline(splitter,consoleTo,',');
                    getline(splitter,warranty,',');
                    Accessory* a = new Accessory(stoi(copies), stof(price), title, consoleTo, to_bool(condition), stoi(warranty));
                    gameStock.add(a);

                    std::cout << "\nRead:\t" << a->toString() << "\n";

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
else {
    std::cout << "Can't read from file. Inventory not loaded.\n";
}
}


void Inventory::toFile(std::string filename){
std::ofstream outf(filename);
if (outf){
    if(filename == "game.txt"){
        for(int i = 0; i < numGames; i++){
            ItemADT* curr = gameStock.get(i);
            if(curr != nullptr){
                outf << curr->fileFormat() + ",\n";
            }
        }
    }

    if(filename == "console.txt"){
        for(int i = 0; i < numConsoles; i++){
            ItemADT* curr = consoleStock.get(i);
            if(curr != nullptr){
                outf << curr->fileFormat() + ",\n";
            }
        }

    }

    if(filename == "accessory.txt"){
        for(int i = 0; i < numAccessories; i++){
            ItemADT* curr = acessStock.get(i);
            if(curr != nullptr){
                outf << curr->fileFormat() + ",\n";
            }
        }
    }   
    outf.close();
}
else { // Print an error and exit
    std::cout << "Unable to write to file.\n";
}
}
```

Comment: `they do not work`: Could you edit question and describe what is happening, and what you expect ? As such, pretty hard to guess...

Comment: What error occurs?  Have to checked that the files are closed after the read and write operation?

Comment: Sorry about that, question has been edited

Answer (score 0):

When i tested it, if i open an ifstream and an ofstream, then read using the ifstream it didnt read, but it would write.

```
ifstream fin("test.txt");
ofstream fout("test.txt");
string str;

fin >> str;    
cout << str << endl;

str = "foo";
fout << str;

fin.close();
fout.close();
```

when i opened the ofstream when i was done reading, it worked fine. It could be a problem with not closing the file after the reading, and before you open it again for another operation.

Comment: One of my group members tried moving the input stream's close into the fromFile function so it closes itself immediately after reading, but we're still having the same problem.